# simple_HTML_dom - get pagination number & count all table in page

Tags: php, xpath, pagination, simple-html-dom

Iam using simple_HTML_dom and i want to scrape data for pagination and table, so i need to get pagination maximum number, here the html code :

```
<ul class='page'>
   <li class='current'>1</li>
   <li><a href='stok.php?id=2&amp;kode=%'>2</a></li>
   <li><a href='stok.php?id=3&amp;kode=%'>3</a></li>
   <li><a href='stok.php?id=4&amp;kode=%'>4</a></li>
   <li><a href='stok.php?id=5&amp;kode=%'>5</a></li>
   <li><a href='stok.php?id=6&amp;kode=%'>6</a></li>
   <li><a href='stok.php?id=7&amp;kode=%'>7</a></li>
   <li><a href='stok.php?id=8&amp;kode=%'>8</a></li>
   <li><a href='stok.php?id=9&amp;kode=%'>9</a></li>
   <li>...</li>
   <li><a href='stok.php?id=57&amp;kode=%'>57</a></li>
   <li><a href='stok.php?id=58&amp;kode=%'>58</a></li>
</ul>
```

And how to count how many table in page with simple html dom ?

I search on google but nothing found, please help me.

Comment: How are you generating the pagination?

Comment: I want to ask that :D

Comment: You can use a for loop for that.

Comment: i dont understand, can u give me some code maybe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $doc->find('.page li', -1)->text();
// 58
echo count($doc->find('table'));
// number of tables
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

stok.php page

```
<ul class='page'>

<?php
  for($i=1; $i<59; $i++) {
      if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] == $i)
          echo "<li class='current'>".$i."</li>";
      else
          echo "<li><a href='stok.php?id=".$i."&kode=%'>".$i."</a></li>";
  }
  ?>

</ul>
```

Comment: I just want to get maximum page number like "58"

Comment: thank you, i want to ask i = 59 for what ? the page number pagination is not always same, so thats i need to get max number pagination

Comment: Well instead of using 59 use a variable then. Like `for($i=1; $i < $total_page; $i++)`

Comment: ya i want to get total page, not link :D

Comment: Don't get you. How are you determining the number of pages? Getting it from database or manually writing the html?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156624/discussion-between-hengky-st-and-mahbubul-islam).